# How to remove tap valve within shroud (Franke ascona mixer tap)

Tags: plumbing, kitchens, taps

I'm trying to replace the cold tap valve on a Franke Ascona mixer tap.

The valve is slightly recessed in a non removable shroud. The new replacement valve fits a standard 14mm socket set which I can use. However the existing valve I am trying to remove has rounded sides which prevents the socket set from attaching.

I have tried an adjustable spanner but because of the shroud I can't get enough leverage to undo the valve. How can I remove this valve?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can take a pair of locking pliers (use good quality vise grips or something like that, and don't be tempted to use needle nose visegrips), the biggest pair you can get to fit, and insert the visegrips into the circular shroud.  its called parrot beaking.  the vise grips will stick straight out from the shroud (long axis of the pliers parallel to the axis of rotation of the valve.  once you have a grip, and the size of the plier is important here - smaller pliers will fit further in, but larger ones tend to hold better for the next step. you have to find a compromise.  once the pliers are in there and clamped hard, you place a screwdriver or drift punch through the pliers jaws (behind where its clamped to the valve) and apply torque.  just go slow and watch for bending of the jaws away from each other.  you dont want the punch to lever the jaws apart to the point they slip off the brass flats or worse, round them over.  also be wary of rotation.  some valve bodies have right hand threads, some left.

Comment: I used a large adjustable wrench to attach to the valve and then a smaller adjustable wrench attached at 90 degrees to the large adjustable wrench to provide sufficient leverage. I had to use a lot of force but eventually it came loose. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: you are welcome.  fyi - in my experience, vise grips work better than adjustable wrenches for this type of method only because the vise grip lets you make sure you get as solid of a grip on the flats as possible.  adjustables always seem to lead to rounded flats because no matter how you tighten them up, they always seem to be looser than visegrips.  glad you got it out

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried an open-end wrench?

Such as this:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrench#/media/File%3A2008-04-14_Chrome-Vanadium_Wrenches.jpg

It won't fit flat onto the nut but it looks like you could get a good grip on it at a shallow angle. The end of a spanner (adjustable wrench) is quite a bit thicker and harder to maneuver in tight spaces.

Otherwise, you would need a specialty tool to remove it.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I used a large adjustable wrench with decent sized jaws which I tightened as best I could. I found that these were less prone to twisting. Then I used a locking adjustable set of pliers (Mole grips in the UK) which I used to twist the adjustable wrench. Came off really easily with no damage to the faces of the cartridges.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Just replaced my Franke Sion Dual-Lever Mono Mixer Kitchen Tap ceramic disc.

ONLY for six sided shoulder on valve. for older 2 sided buy special tool.

Tools: 2mm Allen key to remove tap head. 14mm Socket (off socket set) thats all you need

regards

steve

Comment: Hi! Thanks for posting your answer. Any chance that you could revise the answer to provide more detail about the tools you describe or, perhaps, a better explanation of what it is you're trying to say? Thanks!